# Why aren't my validation messages showing?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I've got an mvc 5 site, and I'm trying to use the built-in validation, and it's not working.

By "not working" I mean that the validation messages aren't showing.  I can test the model on the httppost action and verify whether or not it's valid.  That part works perfectly.  But I thought that there was a client side validation that should occur before the post.  Also, if not, shouldn't the error message appear after the post anyway?

What am I missing?  I've pasted all the relevant code below.

The markup has the validation data in the elements.

```
<div id="CommentDateDiv" style="display: none;">Comment Date:
    <br />
    <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The CommentDate field is required." id="CommentDate" name="CommentDate" style="width:150px" type="date" />
    <script>
        jQuery(function() {
            jQuery("#CommentDate").kendoDatePicker({
                "format": "M/d/yyyy",
                "min": new Date(2013, 11, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                "max": new Date(2013, 11, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0)
            });
        });
    </script>
</div>
<div>Comment Details:
    <br />
    <textarea class="k-textbox" cols="20" data-val="true" data-val-required="The CommentDetails field is required." id="CommentDetails" name="CommentDetails" rows="2" style="width: 400px; height: 150px;"></textarea>
</div>
```

Here is the model

```
public class CalendarCommentModel
{
    public string CommentType { get; set; }
    public string EventID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string CommentDate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string CommentDetails { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the markup(using kendo ui)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div style="display: none;">
        <input type="radio" id="EventRadio" name="CommentType" value="event" checked="checked" /><label for="EventRadio">Attach to event</label>
        <input type="radio" id="LooseCommentRadio" name="CommentType" value="loose" /><label for="LooseCommentRadio">Free Comment</label>
    </div>
    <div id="EventSelectorDiv">
        Select Event:<br />
        @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(x => x.EventID).DataTextField("Text")
          .DataValueField("Value")
          .BindTo(@ViewBag.AllEvents).OptionLabel("Select Event...").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 400px;" }))

    </div>
    <div id="CommentDateDiv" style="display: none;">
        Comment Date:<br />
        @(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
          .Name("CommentDate")
          .Min(Convert.ToDateTime(ViewBag.startDate))
          .Max(((DateTime)Convert.ToDateTime(ViewBag.endDate)).AddDays(-1))
          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:150px" })
        )
    </div>
    <div>
        Comment Details:<br />
        @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.CommentDetails, new { @class = "k-textbox", style = "width: 400px; height: 150px;" })

    </div>
    @(Html.Kendo().Button()
    .Name("SaveButton")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { type = "submit" })
      .Content("Save Comment"))
}
```

Also, the appropriate scripts are being added as well.

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have either a validation summary or a validation field in the form.
Try adding either

```
@Html.ValidationSummary()
```

which give you summary of all the errors.

Or if you want it for individual model properties then add something like after commentdetails.

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.CommentDetails, new { @class = "k-textbox", style = "width: 400px; height: 150px;" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CommentDetails)
```

Comment: Since I can't upvote this answer twice, I upvoted it 3 times.  Thanks for your help.